# Add checkbox to shipping method for extra charge

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I would like to add checkbox in shipping method for extra charge if selected.

for that I have overrided `checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`, it displays correctly on shipping method like this [Screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/Wnl7Tklzaz)

[image: Screencast]

But how to make ajax call on it and add charge to shipping method.

also is there any core method to do like this so that it can be available globally like when order create from admin interface.

**EDIT**

Get this work only for cart. But anyone know how to make it globally available. For cart I have to overwrite cart controller `updatepostaction` and set flag to set price based on selected shipping.

How do I make available this on onepage, create order from admin.

Coz there is diffrent method called in onepage controller to set shipping method.

Comment: @Zaheerabbs Any solutions?

Comment: yes i will post it soon :)

Comment: Can you post your solution please?

Comment: Hello @mahmoudismail you can go through this link and download the code and change as per your requirement.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SkJEifzE4Hh30-4I2-NffX2bVROEGQin?usp=sharing

I have just added module file you can add checkbox in your template file it will work.